# How create a custom event handler for ctcall center? iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, event-handling, core-telephony

I am working on an application in which i have a requirement of detect call log info.

Means when ever a call coming and going and then after attending call that will disconnect. So i have detect and send a notification when call disconnect.

For this requirement i have done so much r&d and get some results but when i go through Apple's doc for core telephony framework then there is class "CTCallCenter". This class provide a event handler which will invoke app whenever a call state change.

Now problem is that when i go through document of that class then i get som texts which is shown below

> To handle such call events, define a handler block in your application and assign it to this property. You must implement the handler block to support being invoked from any context.

[link of apple doc for core telephony framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604)

In above text write down that u have to create a event handler and assign to property then it will handle call events.

So problem is that how I create a custom event handler and how make a property and assign to   my custom event handler?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [CoreTelephonyDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTelephonyDemo/Introduction/Intro.html). You will find your answer in there.

The event handler is a block. You can also look at [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)